# Can I have a local network and a VPN connection simultaneously on my Raspberry PI?

Tags: networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian

I have a Raspberry PI 4 4GB and want to have a LAN-connection and a VPN-connection simultaneously active (because I want to access the same website with different IPs, in order to avoid getting banned for too many requests from the same IP).

I thought of some form of virtual environment, so I can run the script with my host environment using my LAN and in the virtual environment using a VPN-Client.

What's the best approach? As far as I know, VirtualBox can't be used on Raspbian, but could I create a Docker container instead?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Aside from "avoinding getting banned"... Which VPN client are you using? What you request is generally something that is supposed to work by default, unless the VPN app actively tries to prevent it ("leak prevention" etc.)

Comment: it is supposed to work without virtualisation? I use NordVPN atm but am willing to switch to whatever is needed.